# Making table consisting all customers and last orders of each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say, I have two tables: Customers and Orders. I need to get result consisting all customers and their last order.

I am trying to make this query, because my bigger goal is to iterate over all customers and their last orders to get crucial information. I am trying to do this using cursor, so I need that table.

-edit-
I have MSSQL database on SQL 2014 server.
I have relation one-to-many, where customers have many orders.

I need to migrate data from one DB to another with different data schema. I thought about making sql script to get data from one DB and then using cursor and variables to insert data to a new one. There are not many records so performance is not an issue.

Comment: post at least the table structures, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What "crucial" information?  You can probably do that work in a query as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you mind if i also use those comments

Comment: Customers and Orders are only examples. Last 'order' record has information about current state of debt.

Answer (score 0):

Let us have `Customer(cid PK, and possibly other columns)` and `Orders(cid FK, order_time)` having 1:N cardinality. The the solution can be along these lines:

```
select c.*, o.*
from customer c
join orders o on c.cid = o.cid
join
(
  select cid, max(order_time) max_order_time
  from orders
  group by cid
) t on o.cid = t.cid and
       o.order_time = t.max_order_time
```

Comment: This works nicely, but I actually need to select last order from 2017 year so max function won't work here.

Comment: @tomek-a and what prevent you to add `where year(order_time) = 2017` condition to the subquery?

Comment: Yeah nothing really :P
Your solution works well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use `row_number()`:

```
select
from customer c join
     (select o.*, row_number() over (partition by cid order by order_time desc) as seqnum
      from orders o
      where order_time < '2018-01-01' and order_time >= '2017-01-01'
     ) o
     on c.cid = o.cid and o.seqnum = 1;
```